# How can I play sound in JavaScript, without using the <audio> tag?

Tags: javascript, html

How can play sound using JavaScript only, without using the `<audio>` tag?

I'm using:

```
var audio = {};
audio["walk"] = new Audio();
audio["walk"].src = "Scr/dave.wma"
audio["walk"].load()
setTimeout('audio["walk"].play()',1000);
```

But it doesn’t play?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Delan says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7116000/how-can-play-sound-in-javascript-only-and-dont-use-audio-tag/7116006#7116006), no browser supports WMA.

However, your code still has a problem.

You need to wait until the `audio` has loaded.

```
var audio = {};
audio["walk"] = new Audio();
audio["walk"].src = "Scr/dave.wma"
audio["walk"].addEventListener('load', function() {
    audio["walk"].play();
});
```

Answer (score 6):

No browsers support the Windows Media Audio format.

You should be using the Ogg Vorbis, MP3 and Wave formats.

Here is a table of audio format support in the five major browsers:

```
                     Ogg Vorbis        MP3        Wave
Firefox                  *                          *
Safari                                  *           *
Chrome                   *              *
Opera                    *                          *
Internet Explorer                       *           *
```

Please note: the above table may be outdated.

In addition, as alex has stated, the statements are asynchronous and do not wait for the audio file to have loaded. You will need to listen for the `load` event and call `play` within the event handler.